# Group by on selected rows in columns

Tags: python, pandas

There are lots of different vendors and I need the sum of selected vendors. What should I do in this code?

I have tried to get all the values in vendor columns but I need the sum of the amount of the selected vendors in all vendors list

```
df.groupby('Vendor')['Amount'].sum()

Vendor
#1 PARTY SUPPLIES               347.06
#101 BLUE CORN                  379.21
#15 VS                          116.87
#17 VS                          128.90
#18 VS                          689.36
#22 PREFERRED PUMP & EQUI      1686.23
#41 BRIO COUNTRY CLUB           919.75
#44 BRAVO| MEMORIAL SQUA        227.40
0                                55.16
003 CENTURYLINK MY ACCOUN      1659.79
004 CENTURYLINK IVR            2252.84
016BOX STUDIO MOVIE GRIL         70.00
016FBV STUDIO MOVIE GRIL        155.30
0187 CED                         34.70
0386 - MOTEL 6                   39.99
0410 AMERICAN                  5359.89
045 OBI               086       708.11

Name: Amount, Length: 86727, dtype: float64
```

I am hoping to get the following:

```
0386 - MOTEL 6                   39.99
0410 AMERICAN                  5359.89
045 OBI               086       708.11
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example input and example output? From your current output it's not clear how (a) your input `df` looks like and (b) where you're hoping to get to.

Comment: I am hoping to get the following from the above list of vendors:016BOX STUDIO MOVIE GRIL         70.00
016FBV STUDIO MOVIE GRIL        155.30
0187 CED                         34.70
0386 - MOTEL 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter for your selected vendors first then group by.

Since your question isn't clear about your vendor list and desired output, here's a rough idea of what I think you need:

```
v = df['vendors'].isin(your_list_of_venors_here)
df[v].groupby('Vendor')['Amount'].sum()
```